# react-native-youtube: App crashes after switching to another screen and back

Tags: react-native

Please, help me to solve the proplem with app crash. I use react-native-youtube and everything works as expected except of one moment: after navigating to another screen and returning back - the app crashes without eny error in logs. Screens are placed in different stacks (doesn't sure if it means something).

Does anyone know what can be the reason of such error?

Comment: try this : https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube

Comment: Thanks, but I use this library... and error uccored there...

Comment: Finally, I've managed to find the reason... So, for Those who faced the same problem - the answer is to add "resumePlayAndroid={false}" property to player component (didn't mentioned in docs). For more - read https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube/issues/238#issuecomment-468600923

Comment: The solution works perfectly for now https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube/issues/238#issuecomment-944239253

Answer (score 1):

**This is a WebView library issue and the fix is to set its opacity to 0.99.**

```
               <YoutubePlayer 
                play={false}
                videoId={videoId}
                webViewStyle={{opacity: 0.99}}.  <==== add this
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<YoutubePlayer 
            play={false}
            videoId={videoId}
            resumePlayAndroid={false} <-- this helps (back crash)
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the above worked for me with **react-navigation v6** but I've found a workaround.

To `webViewProps`, you can pass `androidLayerType` which has 3 possible values:

- `none` (no video is rendered)
- `software` (I also got no video on test device)
- `hardware` (this setting is actually rendering the video layer but also causing the crash)

If you first pass `software` and then switch it to `hardware` as soon as the video is ready for rendering then there is no crash anymore.

```
const [isReadyForRender, setIsReadyForRender] = useState(false);

function onReady() {
    setIsReadyForRender(true)
}

<YoutubePlayer
    height={height}
    play={playing}
    videoId={videoId}
    onReady={onReady}
    webViewStyle={{opacity: 0.99, display: isReadyForRender ? 'flex' : 'none'}}
    webViewProps={{androidLayerType: isReadyForRender ? 'hardware' : 'software'}}
/>
```